# Flash builder error on open

Tags: eclipse, flash, error-handling, flash-builder

I have a serious problem with Flash builder 4.6

When I open it A display error message appear on the screen and give me some logs files to see. The problem is that I don't know what to do with the logs and how to fix it :s

Here are the logs :

[Logs file](http://studiogizmo.be/logs/logs.zip)

If you have any idea, tips or whatever. i'l give you all my respect !!

Thanks you in advance

Simon